# How do i create buttons with different events

Tags: c#, button, events

```
            for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            {
                bttn = "b" + i;
                Button b = new Button
                {
                    Width= 100,
                    Name = "b" + i,
                    Text = "hey" + i,
                Location = new Point(centerLine.Location.X+i*100,centerLine.Location.Y),
                };
                b.Click += (sender1, e1) =>
                {
                    textBox1.Text += "wtf"+i;
                };
                this.Controls.Add(b);
            }
```

The problem I have is I don't know how to make multiple events, i have only one sender, and as i understand it, that sender just determines my event so at the end of the for loop it will be equal to the last event i made.

Ok so i tried to create 4 buttons with events. But the thing is when i press any button the event is the same, wtf4 gets added to the text box its like the last button determines all events. center line is just a line i have that helps me create these buttons to a specific spot. How do i make these events different?

Comment: You cannot use `i` there. You could set the Tag of your Buttons to `i`, if that's all there is to it. `sender1` is the Button that raised the event, so cast it to `Button` or `Control` to read its Tag. -- NOTE: if you create these Buttons more than once, don't use a Lambda to subscribe to the event, use a method (so you can easily unsubscribe when the Buttons are disposed).

Comment: tag of my button? whats a tag? sender1 isnt the button. i legit understand 0 of what ur talking about, this is for a project btw and we werent taught anything close enough to do it, we are just self learning here and there

Comment: Each Control (a Button is a Control) has a `Tag` property. You can set it to anything you want (literally *anything*).  -- When a Control raises an event, the `sender` Object is the reference to the Control that raised the event. You can then cast `sender` to a specific Type or, as in this case - since the `Tag` property belongs to the `Control` class from which `Button` derives - to `Control`. e.g., `var value = (sender as Control).Tag;` or  `var value = (sender as Button).Tag;` or `var value = ((Button)sender).Tag;` or `var value = ((Control)sender).Tag;`

Comment: but im creating 4 seperate buttons, they are created with seperate names and stuff but the event isnt, are u saying the sender should be unique or?

Comment: @Jimi ok so a sender is a refrence which is similar to a pointer ok so i need to set a separate sender for each button, how do i do that?

Comment: You don't need to *set a separate sender for each button*, you're not setting anything, the Button that raises the event sets itself as the *sender* object. Since you're using the same event handler for all your Buttons, if you click `Button1`, then `sender` is the reference to `Button1`. Thus, if you write, e.g., `string buttonText = (sender as Control).Text;` or `string buttonName = (sender as Control).Name;`, you'll get the Text and Name of `Button1`. The same for all other Buttons that share the same handler. Of course you can also write `sender as Button`, since you know the Type.

Comment: @Jimi so how do i create a dynamic amount of buttons with dynamic amount  of events? Btw we just scratches the surface of c# and i actually never dealt with multiple senders, we actually didnt do anything with senders but yeah

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to get the name of the sender

```
for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    bttn = "b" + i;
    Button b = new Button
    {
        Width= 100,
        Name = "b" + i,
        Text = "hey" + i,
        Location = new Point(centerLine.Location.X+i*100,centerLine.Location.Y),
    };
    b.Click += (sender1, e1) =>
    {
        textBox1.Text += ((Button)sender1).Name;
    };
    this.Controls.Add(b);
}
```

Comment: how do i get the name of the sender?

Comment: @Ethereallie the sender is the button which raised the event.

Comment: what do u mean by raised? u mean that did the event or?

Comment: sender is type of object. If you look the code, you can see that by casting sender as a button you get access to all properties of your button, the Name as well. The variable 'sender' is the reference of the object that raised, triggered, fired the event.